# GWT Activity : How to use an activity, place, eventbus and uibinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder, event-bus

I'm new at GWT and I wonder myself how to use an Activity, Place ,EventBus and UIbinder.
The layout of my app is smth like this :

Widget 1:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel ui:field="myPanel" unit='PX'>
    <g:north size='60'>
        <m:HeaderPanelImpl styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}' ui:field='headerPanel' />
    </g:north>
    <g:south size='60'>
        <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}' ui:field='footerPanel' />
    </g:south>
    <g:center>
        <g:SimpleLayoutPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}' ui:field='centerPanel' />
    </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Here in "widget1.headerPanel" a have navigation which controls which widget to be shown in “widget1.centerPanel”.
The widgets which have to be shown in  “widget1.centerPanel” are “widget2.0” and ”widget2.1”.

Widget2.0

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX'>
    <g:north size='100'>
        <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}'>
            <g:Label>TopPanel</g:Label>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:west size='200'>
        <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}'>
            <g:Label>LeftPanel</g:Label>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:west>
    <g:east size='200'>
        <g:HTMLPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}'>
            <g:Label>RightPanel</g:Label>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:east>
    <g:center>
        <g:SimpleLayoutPanel styleName='{res.style.panelBorder}' ui:field='centerPanel' />
    </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Widget2.1

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Label>Settings</g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In ”widget2.0.topPanel” I have navigation which controls which widget will be shown  in “widget2.0.centerPanel”
The widgets which have to be shown in  “widget2.centerPanel” are “widget3.0” and ”widget3.1”.

Widget3.0

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Label>Content 1</g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Widget3.1

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Label>Content 2</g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

My question is how to handle "onPlaceChangeEvent" ?

In example if url is mydomain.com/myapp.html#home:content1
the app has to show widget 1, widget 2.0 and widget 3.0

If the url is mydomain.com/myapp.html#home:content2
the app has to show widget1,  widget 2.0 and widget 3.1

If the url is mydomain.com/myapp.html#settings
the app has to show widget1 and  widget 2.1

I'm wondering between two variants :

1. To create to 2 ActivityManagers. One for the activities from widget1.navigation and one for the activites from  widget2.navigation.  But what happens if widget2 is created before widget 1 ?
2. To create one Activity which creates couple views.

Code:example

```
public class MonthlyViewActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MonthlyView.Presenter {

    private Widget2_0 widget2_0;
    private Widget3_0 widget3_0;

    ......
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        widget2_0 = new Widget2_0();
        widget3_0 = new Widget3_0();
    ..........
    }
    .... 
}
```

What is the best practice for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse create a MVP architecture in your project it will create many files like activity, place, one interface, one implementation class and a corresponding ui xml class. you have to create a activity mapper and activity history manager class. and in your on lode module set a default place for your application. after words on any event call go to method for any place and provide the link of your page and there check the get the value of  token amd on basis of that value display your widgets what you want to display.